# How to get a proper rendering of my node tree?

Tags: javascript, dom, tree

I want to build a DOM tree using a JS object (classic topic). I achieved most of the work but I am getting a non sense result: DOM tree appear to be created correctly BUT all nodes are rendered flatten on a single line and Input element is clipped.

I highly suspect the `buildNode` function not working correctly, but I can not find the flaw.

```js
/**** FILTERS ****/
// TODO : change crappy filter using dictionnary
const attrOnly = (str) => !(str === 'content' || str === 'tag' || str === 'children');

/**** TESTS ****/
const hasChildren = (obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('children'),
      hasContent = (obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('content');

// TODO: search for namespace given a tag name (SVG)
const findNameSpace = (str) => null;

// Build node with correct attributes and values
const buildNode = function (element, parent) {
  const tag = (element.tag || 'div'),
        tagAttr = Object.keys(element).filter(attrOnly),
        node = document.createElementNS(findNameSpace(tag), tag);
  tagAttr.forEach(
    (attr) => node.setAttributeNS(findNameSpace(tag), attr, element[attr])
  );
  hasContent(element) ? node.innerHTML = element.content : null;
  return parent.appendChild(node);
}

// Walk along the tree mapping current element with function f.
function walkTree(f, element, parent) {
  const current = f(element, parent);
  // Reccursively walk children, if necessary
  (hasChildren(element) && element.children.forEach(
    child => walkTree(f, child, current)
  ));
};

let tree = {
  tag: 'div',
  id: 'tree',
  children: [{
    tag: 'section',
    id: 'section-l1-1',
    class: 'l1',
    content: 'Use <em>me</em> as I am, I am gorgeous!',
    children: [{
      tag: 'div',
      id: 'div-l2',
      class: 'l2',
      children: [{
        tag: 'p',
        content: 'Here is a nested paragraph.'
      }]
    }, {
      tag: 'form',
      id: 'form-l2',
      class: 'l2',
      onsubmit: 'alert("Function called!");',
      children: [{
        tag: 'input',
        type: 'text',
        id: 'input-l3',
        class: 'l3',
        value: 'self-closing tag case!'
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    tag: 'footer',
    id: 'end-page',
    class: 'l1',
    content: 'This is a running experiment.'
  }]
};

walkTree(buildNode, tree, document.getElementById('seed'));
```

```css
#seed div,form,input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="seed"></div>
```

Comment: The code itself is fine, you just need to declare a new line or append a line ``<br />`` as you go to the same effect.

Comment: I should not need any `<br />`... I edited the snippet and added some style `display: block`. Input is still hidden. It looks like all nodes are concatenated or something.

Comment: If I manually edit the form's node using developer tools, the input appears! What an insane bug...!

Answer (score 0):

So I found that namespaces handling was my problem. As I wanted to get render HTML elements and SVG elements at the same time, I needed that...

I did not find a proper fix to that problem so I set lower expectations and only render HTML using `document.createElement()` (and `Node.setAttribute()`) instead of `document.createElementNS()` (and `Node.setAttributeNS()`).

To see how far I get with namespace handling:

```js
/* DICTIONARIES */
const nonAttr = ['content', 'tag', 'children'],
      // Search for tag's special namespace. Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/namespaces.html
      tagNamespace = {
        'svg': 'https://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      };

/**** FILTERS ****/
const attrOnly = (str) => !(nonAttr.includes(str));

/**** TESTS ****/
const hasChildren = (obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('children'),
      hasContent = (obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('content');

// Search for namespace given a tag name
const findNameSpace = (str) => (tagNamespace[str] || 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');

// Build node with correct attributes and values
const buildNode = function (element, parent) {
  const tag = (element.tag || 'div'),
        tagAttr = Object.keys(element).filter(attrOnly),
        node = document.createElementNS(findNameSpace(tag), tag);
  tagAttr.forEach(
    (attr) => node.setAttribute(attr, element[attr])
  );
  hasContent(element) ? node.innerHTML = element.content : null;
  return parent.appendChild(node);
}

// Walk along the tree mapping current element with function f.
function walkTree(f, element, parent) {
  const current = f(element, parent);
  // Reccursively walk children, if necessary
  (hasChildren(element) && element.children.forEach(
    child => walkTree(f, child, current)
  ));
};

let tree = {
  tag: 'div',
  id: 'tree',
  children: [{
    tag: 'section',
    id: 'section-l1-1',
    class: 'l1',
    content: 'Use <em>me</em> as I am, I am gorgeous!',
    children: [{
      tag: 'div',
      id: 'div-l2',
      class: 'l2',
      children: [{
        tag: 'p',
        content: 'Here is a nested paragraph.'
      }]
    }, {
      tag: 'form',
      id: 'form-l2',
      class: 'l2',
      onsubmit: 'alert("Function called!");',
      action: '',
      method: 'GET',
      children: [{
        tag: 'input',
        type: 'text',
        id: 'text-l3',
        name: 'text-l3',
        class: 'l3',
        placeholder: 'self-closing tag case!'
      },{
        tag: 'input',
        type: 'submit',
        id: 'submit-l3',
        name: 'submit-l3',
        class: 'l3',
        value: 'submit!'
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    tag: 'footer',
    id: 'end-page',
    class: 'l1',
    content: 'This is a running experiment.',
    children: [{
      tag: 'svg',
      class: 'l2',
      children : [{
        tag: 'rect',
        width: '10',
        height: '10',
        fill: 'black'
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

walkTree(buildNode, tree, document.getElementById('seed'));
```

```css
.l1 {
  background-color: DarkGrey;
}
.l2 {
  background-color: Grey;
}
.l3 {
  background-color: LightGrey;
}
.l4 {
  background-color: White;
}
```

```html
<div id="seed"></div>
```

To see working code *without* namespace support:

```js
/* DICTIONARIES */
const nonAttr = ['content', 'tag', 'children'];

/**** FILTERS ****/
const attrOnly = (str) => !(nonAttr.includes(str));

/**** TESTS ****/
const hasChildren = (obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('children'),
  hasContent = (obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('content');


// Build node with correct attributes and values
const buildNode = function(element, parent) {
  const tag = (element.tag || 'div'),
    tagAttr = Object.keys(element).filter(attrOnly),
    node = document.createElement(tag);
  tagAttr.forEach(
    (attr) => node.setAttribute(attr, element[attr])
  );
  hasContent(element) ? node.innerHTML = element.content : null;
  return parent.appendChild(node);
}

// Walk along the tree mapping current element with function f.
function walkTree(f, element, parent) {
  const current = f(element, parent);
  // Reccursively walk children, if necessary
  (hasChildren(element) && element.children.forEach(
    child => walkTree(f, child, current)
  ));
};

let tree = {
  tag: 'div',
  id: 'tree',
  children: [{
    tag: 'section',
    id: 'section-l1-1',
    class: 'l1',
    content: 'Use <em>me</em> as I am, I am gorgeous!',
    children: [{
      tag: 'div',
      id: 'div-l2',
      class: 'l2',
      children: [{
        tag: 'p',
        content: 'Here is a nested paragraph.'
      }]
    }, {
      tag: 'form',
      id: 'form-l2',
      class: 'l2',
      onsubmit: 'alert("Function called!");',
      action: '',
      method: 'GET',
      children: [{
        tag: 'input',
        type: 'text',
        id: 'text-l3',
        name: 'text-l3',
        class: 'l3',
        placeholder: 'self-closing tag case!'
      }, {
        tag: 'input',
        type: 'submit',
        id: 'submit-l3',
        name: 'submit-l3',
        class: 'l3',
        value: 'submit!'
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    tag: 'footer',
    id: 'end-page',
    class: 'l1',
    content: 'This is a running experiment.',
    // SVG CAN'T GET RENDERED BECAUSE NAMESPACES
    children: [{
      tag: 'svg',
      class: 'l2',
      children: [{
        tag: 'rect',
        fill: 'black'
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

walkTree(buildNode, tree, document.getElementById('seed'));
```

```css
.l1 {
  background-color: DarkGrey;
}

.l2 {
  background-color: Grey;
}

.l3 {
  background-color: LightGrey;
}

.l4 {
  background-color: White;
}
```

```html
<div id="seed"></div>
```

PS. I have to say that I have dirt in my mouth...